# How to add remote project's subfolder to my project in git

Tags: git

I'm interesting, is it possible to add remote project's (or different branch of same project) subfolder into subfolder in by branch.

*Example:*
Let's have Project-1.git with 2 subfolders in it's master branch:

```
Project-1:
- folder-A
- folder-B
```

and let's our project is Project-2.git.

Is it possible to add Project-1's folder-A into my project, without folder-B?

Of course I want to track changes in folder-A, made in Project-1.git

Answer (score 0):

Yes for that you have to use submodules.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

With that you can checkout some other git projects into your projects and that modules are managed by its own GIT.

Comment: Is it possible to add only part of remote repository as submodule?

Comment: How should that work? ;) you need the complete repository. Otherwise you have to checkout the project on another place and set a symlink for example and ignore that file for the link.

Comment: In my case I do not need complete repository, but only subfolder. If I checkout project to another place, how git will track it?

Comment: If its another project you shouldn't modify it so git don't recognize. If its for your own project you should have a look at packages with composer and satis for example.

Comment: I have remote project with lot of libraries, and I do not need all of that libraries in my project. I need only 1. So I'm searching the way how to add this library with most git-style way - with tracking of all it's changes. Something like subtree, but not for branch root tree, but for any particular tree.

Comment: I see a kind of workaround:
in project-1, create branch Folder-1, using filter-branch, for example, and then add it as a subtree to project-2. But it will not be tracked automatically.